# Countablity of a monotonous set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> A set $X$ is monotonous if for every $A\in X$ and for all $B\subseteq A$ : $B\in X$

Prove or disprove: $M = \{X\subseteq P(\mathbb{N})|X \text{ is monotonous}\}$ is countable.

I've tried disproving this by diagonalization, but i can't make it so that the diagonal object will be monotonous.

Comment: Perhaps in the definition of $M$, $X$ should be a subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't it true that if n < m then n is a subset of m?  So if M is monotonous and n is in M wouldn't mean 0,1,....n all be in M.  So wouldn't the monotonous sets simply be the sets N_k={0,1,2...k} for any k, as well as the set N itself? Obviously  that's countable?

Comment: @fleablood No, because $\{\{3000\}, \{1\}\}$ is also a monotonous set.

Comment: But $\{\{3000\},\{1\}\}\not \in P(\mathbb N)$ and .... oh, gar....  I misread the problem.  I read it as M = {x in P(N)|x monotonous} and not as M= {x subset P(N)| x monotonous}

Comment: Oh, I didn't misread the problem.  You edited it to change the definition of M.  Notice $\{X \in P(N)|X monotonous\} \ne \{X \subset P(N)|X monotonous\}$.  $\{\{3000\},\{1\}\} \not \in P(N)$ but $\{\{3000\}, \{1\}\} \subset P(N)$

Comment: That error was on your part; not mine.  (Unless I also made a different error.)

Comment: I think:  h: M -> {0,1}^inf via h(x) = (a_1,a_2,a_3,........); a_k = 1 if k is in any of the elements of x and a_k = 1 if k is not in any of the elements in x.  If we can show that that exists a monotonic subset of P(N) that does contain any specific k and a monotonic subset that does not, the h is a surjection to an uncountable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  The question has been edited and changed since I posted this and this post no longer answers the question that was asked.

The original question defined
$M = \{x \in P(\mathbb N)|x \text { is monotonous}\} = \{x \subset \mathbb N| x  \text{ is monotonous}\}$ .

The question has been edited to define
$M = \{x \subset P(\mathbb N)|x \text { is monotonous}\} = \{x=\{W_{\alpha}\} |W_{\alpha} \subset \mathbb N \forall \alpha; x  \text{ is monotonous}\}$

Those are two entirely different sets.

== New answer written AFTER the post was accepted and not yet deserving of the accepted answer status==

Completely different answer for the new definition of $M$.

Let $K$ be any set of natural numbers.  Let $W = P(K) \subset P(\mathbb N)$.   $B \subset A \in W \implies B\subset A \subset K\implies B \subset K \implies B\in W$.  So $W$ is monotonic.  So $W \in M$.

So for any $K$ a set of natural numbers there will be elements that $M$ that contain only subsets of $K$.

So $h:M\rightarrow P(\mathbb N)$ via $h(X) = \{k| \exists A\in X; k \in A\}$ is a surjection.

$P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable so $M$ is uncountable.

== old answer written and accepted BEFORE the edit that changed the question entirely. Although it was the accepted answer it does not deserve to be as it answers an ENTIRELY different question. ==

*EDIT:  I have may a rather obvious error but I'm keeping this for reference.*

*I may have a fundamental misconception of natural numbers of sets and this answer is wrong, but I really don't think so*.

As sets, then natural numbers are

$0 = \emptyset$ and

$n+1 = n \cup \{n\}= \{0,1,2....n\}$.

So if $n < m$ then $n \subset m$.

So if $X \subset \mathbb N$ and $X$ is monotonous and $m \in X$ then for all $n < m$, $n \subset m$ so $n \in X$.  So $X$ is either $0 = \emptyset$.  Or $X$ is  a set $ \{0,....,k\}=k+1$ for some maximal element $k$, or $X$ has no maximal element and $X = \mathbb N$.

*Edit; I was correct in noting if I $n < m$ then $n \in X$ so $X$ is either the emptyset, contains all the the elements of of of some $\{0,.....k\}$ or contains all then natural numbers. But I forgot to consider that that $X$ might, and **would** contain additional elements that are not natural numbers at all. i.e. if $m \in X$ then for all $n < m$, $n \in X$ but also all $\{m\}$ are also in $X$.*

So $M = \{X \in P(\mathbb N)|M \text{ is monotonous}\} = \mathbb N \cup\{\mathbb N\}$

*This isn't actually true.  As $n \in X$ implies $n-1, \{n-1\} \in X$ and as $\{n-1\}$ is not an natural number for any $n > 1$ then no $n > 1$ is in any $X \in M$.*

*So $M = \{0,1\}$*.

$\mathbb N$ is countable and adding one (or any countable number of) elements to a set results in a countable set so $M = \{X \in P(\mathbb N)|M \text{ is monotonous}\} =  \mathbb N \cup \{\mathbb N\}$ is countable.

If you really need to bijection it is $h(0) = \mathbb N; h(k) = k-1 \forall k > 0$

=== redoing ==

Let $M = \{X \in P(\mathbb N)|X \text{ is monotonous}\}$.

Let $X \in M$ and let $n \in X; n > 1$.  Then $n = n-1 \cup {n-1}$.  So $\{n-1\} \in X$.  But $\{n-1\} \not \in \mathbb N$ as all $k > 1; k \in \mathbb N$ are a set $k-1 \cup \{k-1\}$ which have at least two elements.

So $X \not \subset M$ so $X \not \in P(\mathbb N)$.

Thus if $X \in M$ then $X= \emptyset = 0; X = \{0\} = 1; X = \{0,1\}=2$ or $X = \{1\} \not \in \mathbb N$.  $X = 0 = \emptyset$, $ X = 1 =\{\emptyset\}$ and $X = 2 = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ are monotonous.

So $M = \{0,1,2\}$.

Which is basically Hagen van Eitzen's post.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $X\in M$. Then $X\subset \omega$. Assume $n\in X$ for some $n>0$. As  $n=(n-1)\cup\{n-1\}$, this implies  $\{n-1\}\in X$. But $\{n-1\}$ is not an ordinal unless $n-1=0$. We conclude that $X\subseteq \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, but we don't use ordinals, we either disprove by diagonalization or prove by a bijection to a countable set.

Comment: I believe that the point is that unless you've already defined $\mathbb{N}$ as some sort of ordinal, the question doesn't make sense. If you have, then Hagen's answer gives you a bijection to a countable (finite) set.

Comment: I don't understand that answer at all.

Comment: This answers says: if X in M then X $\subset$ N. (This was your old definition of M).  Let n in N. Then if we view n as a set, n=(n-1) $\cup $ {n-1}. So as M is mono and {n-1} $\subset $ n, {n-1} in M.  But {n-1} isn't a natural number at all.  Unless n-1=0.  So X={0}=1, or X=emptyset=0.  So M={0,1} which is finite.

Comment: Which, by 5 he way shows my old answer was incorrect.  My new one might be good though.

Comment: Wait.  Wouldn't X = {0,1} be acceptable?  if $B \subset A \in \{0,\1}$ then either A = 0; or A = 1.  If A=0 then $B \subset 0 = \emptyset$ means $B= \emptyset = 0 \in X$.  If A = 1 = {0} then $B \subset 1 = \{0\}$ means $B = \emptyset = 0 \in X$ or $B = \{0\} = 1 \in X$. So X = emptyset=0 or X = {emptyset}= 1; or {emptyset, {emptyset}}=w so $M = {0,1,2}$.